# How do I add extra data to a submitted form in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a simple form that only uploads an image. However, in my database I want to extract and record some EXIF data from that image.

I'm not sure what to use in Symfony2. It does't seem like the right place to calculate this extra information in the Entity. Where else could I put it?

```
<?php

namespace Timeline\DefaultBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Document
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        // extract EXIF here?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine events can work nicely as long as you don't need to modify another entity.

I think the best way to handle your case would be to use form events.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data

For example you could use a POST_SUBMIT event, and dynamically add a 'exif' text field, and on your entity a $exif property mapping your database field.

```
class Document
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $exif;
}

class DocumentType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file')
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $data = $event->getData();
                $data['exif'] = 'data';
                $event->setData($data);

                $form->remove('exif');
                $form->add('exif', 'string');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Edit #1 :
After further research, the only way I found is to define 'exif' key in data array and 'exif' field in form, so it will be able to mapped it to your entity.
I didn't found a way to solve the problem of the remaining 'exif' field in the form after submission. If you define it as hidden, or do not use {{ form_rest() }}, it will not appear, but this not so clean ...

Comment: I get the error "You cannot add children to a submitted form" but if I change to "PRE_SUBMIT" the exif form fields are displayed. ```$form->add('exif','collection',array('data' => array("a" => 'some data',"b" => "some data","c" => "some data")));``` is what I am trying to add to the submitted form data

Comment: So using "PRE_SUBMIT" event works for you ? Or did you still have trouble ? I did'nt get it.

Comment: POST_SUBMIT gives me the children error. PRE_SUBMIT does not record the data, it add ```<input>``` boxes to the form after submitting and displaying the page.

Comment: I've updated my answer. For the record problem it should be solved, but for the input boxes it's not really reliable...

Comment: thanks for your time olaurendeau. Like you say, I'm sure there is a cleaner way so I will update this if I ever find it, but I'll use this method for now. Thanks!